# Command "pip3 install --user guizero" fails: "No matching distribution found"

Tags: python, macos

I have to install the module [guizero](https://github.com/lawsie/guizero) for a piece of Python homework I've been given but it's not working.

This is all on Terminal on my Mac, version 10.7.5

People have said that I go to `Library/Python` but this is another problem. My MAC doesn't show me any folders named `Python` in Library. This is what the Library Folder looks like:

[Library Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eunN.jpg)

The command I'm using is

```
pip3 install --user guizero
```

and I get this error:

```
Could not find a version the satisfies the requirement guizero (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for guizero
```

Can anyone help with this?!

Comment: download the .whl file and install it from your path https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guizero/0.2.1#downloads

Comment: I'd say add which version of OSX you're on, just for complete information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your pip version:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Or  `pip install guizero version==0.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

Pip can't just magically invent what guizero is. You need to download `guizero-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl` from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guizero. Save it in your `Library/Python/2.5/site-packages` (replace 2.5 with your version) folder and then type `pip install guizero-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl` in the terminal (typing guiz and tab twice should auto complete the file name for you)

EDIT

First install easy_install

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | sudo python`

Then install pip

`sudo easy_install pip`

You can now install any module using

`pip install guizero`

Comment: How do you get to Python/Scripts? Keep in mind that I'm using a mac. If you can explaib that and it works I'll accept your answer.